# Wordpress Jquery Error

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I just started working on wordpress after some time,

When some client gave me his website to make some changes then I tried first checking website on google chrome and try to solve the errors.

First error was like this,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function
```

on the line was

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

then I google for some time, i tried to solve problem by putting this line

```
(function($){
```

but then my jquery was not loading before dome ready, and many functions inside that js file was not load before dom gets ready....

I am exactly don't able to understand that, how to solve this problem.

If i am able to rectify errors but then my function won't load. So how to solve this problem ?

Comment: try using `jQuery` instead of `$` there may be confliction between jquery and prototype.

Comment: Are you sure jQuery is getting included in your page where this code is?Have you also included Mootools,Prototype or any other JS library in that page also?

Comment: yes, i have added many js library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

by

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

Comment: after putting that,
now error is like thatObject [object Object] has no method xya...

Comment: What plugins are you using? Are you loading jQuery before loading the JS files?

Comment: with jQuery(document).ready(function($){ and at last put (jQuery).. :)